# Question about quadrilaterals!

Tags: geometry

In quadrilateral QRTS, we have QR = 11, QS = 9, and ST=2. Sides {RQ} and {ST} are extended past Q and S, respectively, to meet at point P. If PS = 8 and PQ = 5, then what is RT?

I've tried drawing a diagram but I can't figure out how to solve for RT. Can I solve using similar triangles? Please help!

Comment: What if its a trapezium?

Answer (score 1):

You know $PQ$, $QS$ and $PS$, so you can find the angles of the triangle $PQS$ (use the Law of Cosines). Now, you have the angle $\angle QST$ and you know the length of $ST$, so you can determine (Law of the Cosines again) $QT$ and the angles of the triangle $QST$. Last, you have the angle $\angle TQR$ and the lengths $QT$ and $QR$. Apply again the Law of Cosines and you are done.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Law of Cosines?